# Do questions concerning the *development* of well-known specifications (like CSS) belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just asked a question concerning the development of the CSS3 and CSS4 standards. Specifically, I asked why parts of the specifications were designed as they were: 
[Why was the introduction of the `white-space-collapsing` CSS3 property postponed to CSS-text-4 (possibly as `text-space-collapse`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33917309/1560865)

In a comment I got the reply that my question was "either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion". As a reply I pointed out that the question was very specific, not opinion-based and - if answered properly - should not lead to any discussion.

The comment author then stated that my question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I think he was referring to the definition given in the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Since the CSS3 and CSS4 specifications are definitely unique to software development and commonly used by developers, I was under the imression that such a question therefore belongs on Stack Overflow.

Now I wonder: am I wrong here, do such questions not belong on Stack Overflow after all?
And if not: where do they belong in the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: A bit too opinion based maybe?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I made the 'canned' comment as it's not a "specific, solvable, programming" issue. As such the close reason seems to fit closer than any other.

Comment: It is a water-cooler question.  In the very unlikely case that somebody from the W3 committee shows up and explains why they suck, what are the odds that you are going to do your job differently?  What problem does it solve?  Maybe programmers.se likes it better.

Comment: I was hoping that there are enough people on SO who follow the CSS specification development process closely enough to have the required insights to for example simply give a list of reasons that the specification writers had for their decision in this case. But it is fair to say that an answer would not directly "solve a problem" if you don't consider "lack of knowledge" as a problem.

Comment: @Hauke P.: I'm pretty sure I'm the only one on SO who's neither a browser developer nor a WG member who follows the process - and even I don't follow it *closely* by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @HaukeP. But the answer is right there in your link in red text :s *"This section is still under discussion and may change in future drafts"*. Its postponed because this section of the spec didn't even make it to a final draft yet for whatever reason - likely time pressure and a lack of priority. Its probably not going to be any kind of romantic reason that is going to satisfy the curiosity.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as CSS4. CSS has moved to only improve modules from now on

Answer (score 8):

It's difficult to put a blanket rule down for these, context is really important.

If I can *show you* why something is the way it is in a manner that you can study and reproduce, while also possibly pointing you to documented rationale as explained by a standard, then it's probably a decent question for the site. In other words, an answer might look like:

> Well, if it didn't do [thing], then you'd get [this thing], and that would cause [list of problems]. The rationale is explained in [section of standard]

If the answer more or less boils down to:

> You'd need to ask them to be sure, but I found this discussion on some mailing list that kind of hints at [reason]

.. then you're moving into territory where *most* people would need to guess in order to answer. That's not *always* bad, heck we all take half-blind stabs at problems, but typically these stabs can be vetted for correctness.

You're basically asking why a group reached and executed a decision. And people could probably give you at least a few answers that shine on the efficacy of the decision - but no one could really answer the question on behalf of the group unless they were a part of that process.

> Why doesn't Google's 'go' language have assertions?

This *can* be objectively answered and illustrated because it's [rather well documented](https://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions).

It's not that *all* "Why is something this way?" questions are problematic, it's sort of something that you just know when you see. That's very difficult to articulate beyond strongly preferring questions that can have a single, objective and technically correct answer.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b), which I was only able to answer by - you guessed it - forwarding it to the relevant people. It's about a change that was made that would have had a *serious* impact on websites.

Comment: Here's a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603186/why-does-collection-parallelstream-exist-when-stream-parallel-does-the-sa/24603187#24603187) I wrote that basically boils down to "there's no official documentation, but here's what they said on the mailing list". (With 40 score, it's my best-received SO contribution.) One of the experts, Brian Goetz, is active here and commented that I "unearthed most of it". For that matter, Brian has also answered other rationale questions -- sometimes the expert _is_ here to answer.