# Is asking why a language uses a keyword instead of another more descriptive/obvious one in scope for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask a question about why MATLAB chooses to use `log()` for natural log instead of `ln()`. Since this is a question that really only Mathworks can answer, I wanted to see if it is on-topic to post here or not. My hope was that someone might have seen an explanation in the past and can share it; not so much looking for an answer straight from the horse's mouth.

Is this something I can post on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Technically this is a request for an off-site resource so I'm tempted to call it off-topic.

Comment: This would be a question that only the devs of that project could answer, and the answer would most likely be based primarily on opinion even if the devs found the question and provided an answer.

Comment: I would say that is something only the developers of Matlab could answer and all anyone else could add would be speculation. Now this might have been answered elsewhere so a link could be provided but other than that it would most likely be a guess.

Comment: You should send Matlab/Mathworks a critical bug report.  Why would you want to post it on SO?  Using the wrong base is not the kind of bug that is likely to have been around for long: it's a mega-disaster, and so no-one is likely to have 'seen an explanation in the past'.

Comment: Here's a similar question, the answer I think is applicable here.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289838/1228  This is essentially trivia.  I downvote trivia questions, unless I'm at a bar.

Comment: Thanks, the verdict is pretty clear, and I thought that might be the case. @Will, you make a very good point about the trivia. Is there an SE site were you think this question would be accepted?

Comment: If you start with a [Stack Exchange wide search](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=matlab) you get an idea where those questions could go. You can then head to the site specific meta and/or their help center to verify if the question would fly on that site.

Comment: I would say it is of topic here.  As to why they call the natural log `log()` I would have to say that it is because [in higher level math `log()` is `ln()`](http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/webtexts/numb17.htm)

Comment: lol, I wondered when it would come to light that the base used is correct as designed.

Comment: I'm not sure it's so clear cut, but it might be better not to couch it in terms of language-specific design decisions. There's definitely some info here would be a useful resource for future developers who fall into confusion about `ln`/`log`, as it is somewhat quirky compared to the a decent number of other languages. IMO documenting it on SO wouldn't be such a bad thing. A self-answer along the lines of "Why does log() give bad values?" might be more appropriate.

Comment: Related: [Are language specs and their developments on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306471/3614835), [Do questions concerning the *development* of well-known specifications (like CSS) belong to StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311098/3614835)

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it does not belong on SO for two main reasons: it is primarily opinion based, and it doesn't add programming related value.

**Opinion Based**: Even if you had an authority on the topic (like a representative of Mathworks who was there when that function was written), the answer would still basically be "It is that way because we decided to make it that way". There's no factual, programming related reason (at least it is very unlikely that there is), so it isn't the kind of question we want on SO

**No Added Value**: What benefit would it be to programmers to know that small piece of trivia beyond satiating their curiosity? I would say none.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes there is a publicly available source for the answer.

For example, Matz, the creator of Ruby, has described on a Ruby mailing list why he uses `respond_to?` rather than `responds_to?`, and stated in a talk that using `resque` rather than `rescue` in an old version of Ruby was just a spelling mistake.

If a question sometimes has a publicly available answer, and sometimes doesn't, and the asker doesn't know which category it's in (and they wouldn't, otherwise they wouldn't ask), then it should be ok to ask.

Comment: If everyone follows your advice we and up with lots of unanswerable questions, so it doesn't seem like good advice. Especially since it is very hard to verify that a question is not answerable.